# dns resolving not working in azure environement but curl does

Tags: azure, docker, vue.js, dns

so i have been looking for a solution for a couple off days now. i' am deploying a frontend (dockerized vue.js) and a backend (dockerized asp.net application). both are inside a subnet (containers) inside a vnet. there is a application gateway with a public ip address. the application loadbalancer backendpool is connected to the fqdn of the frontend. there is a private dns zone that redirects the traffic to the loadbalancer static ip of the environnement.

Now the problem i am having is i can curl with the loadbalanced link to the backend example : curl https://backend.example.com this returns a hello world for testing but now when i connect to the frontend true the public ip and do the same (using axios doing the fetch server side and not in the browser) i get that the dns name is not able to be resolved

what could the problem be ?

so i have read the official documentation and the dns resolving should happen automatically. If people have more questions ill try to answer thanks already

Comment: Vue runs in the browser, you need a public DNS record to resolve https://backend.example.com.

Comment: and how would i setup this up sorry quite new to this usealy only do networking